# if else statement in javascript is not working. only in else statement

Tags: javascript, sql

Sorry, i'm still new here. i just want to know where's my error here. my else statement is not working. but the if statement is working. lets assume that all my variables are correct though my conditional statement isnt. i really need help, im stuck here.

expecting result:

i need to add 13 options for my select. but when my if statement is done, and the else statment will take over the variable `hr1`, it stop and skip the process. wherein the option is not added.

for example:

```
hr1 = 9
convertedVar = 20
```

->it will only add the option when the condition is satisfied, `if(hr1 <= convertedVar)`  and then else will skip.

thank you for you help.

```
if(a==mod)
{
    for(i = 0; i <= 13 ; i++) 
    { 
        if(hr1 <= convertedVar)
        {
        document.getElementById('timeId').options[i] = new Option('---','');
        hr1++;
        hr2++;
        }
        else
        {
        document.getElementById('timeId').options[i] = new Option(h1++ + ':00', hr2++ + ':00');
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: how are hr1 and convertedVar assigned? btw, in your else you are doing h1++, not hr1++.

Comment: "lets assume that all my variables are correct though my conditional statement isnt" - I wouldn't do that. First you have to *verify* this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg4trPZFUwc

Comment: The ++ (increment) and -- (decrement) operators have been known to contribute to bad code by encouraging excessive trickiness. They are second only to faulty architecture in enabling to viruses and other security menaces. Also, preincrement/postincrement confusion can produce off-by-one errors that are extremely difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @Dalorzo: there's *nothing* wrong with them. pretty much any tool is dangerous if you don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Dalorzo: right (!) but not the problem here. Simple syntax errors.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thanks man. LOL a simple syntax error that i didnt see cause me too much trouble. THANK YOU VERY MUCH :)

hope to post another question in the future. (sorry im just new here)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about the logic behind this but this seems a typo to me:

```
.... s[i] = new Option(h1++ + ':00', hr2 ....
//                    h1 or hr1 ??
```

You are incrementing the variable `h1` instead of the variable `hr1`
If `h1` isn't known at that time, your loop will stop. As this is the described behavior, 99% sure that this is the error: just a typo.

Comment: document.getElementById(<id>).options[<index>] = new Option(<text>, <value>);

here's from what i know, the format.